# PhpStorm how to increment Recent Find Usages history

Tags: phpstorm

I cannot find any option to increment the history for the "Recent Find Usages".

I would like to see for example my last 10 searches when clicking CTRL+E in PhpStorm.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Select a symbol to find usages for. To do that, place the caret within the desired symbol in the editor, or click the symbol in the Project tool window.
2.Do one of the following:

> **On the main menu, choose Edit | Find | Find Usages**
>
> **Choose Find Usages on the context menu**
>
> Press Alt+F7.
>   more details go to this link [go to this link](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/find-tool-window.html)